# Simultaneous density function of two continuous variables, X and Y.

Tags: probability, statistics, continuity

I'm having issues with calculating the simultaneous density function of two continuous variables, X and Y. I took a screenshot of the information:

[image]

How should I start? I know that if the two variables are independent, the simultaneous density function is given by $f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ , but I only know $f_Y(y)=e^{-y}$ ...

/Christine

Comment: I just noticed that the first function, f_Xly(x)=ye^-yx maybe gives the marginal density function of X? Or am I wrong?

If it's true, I guess I should just multiply the two marginal density functions with each other to get the simultaneous density function?? :)

Comment: sounds like you are on the right track.

Comment: but that first function you mentioned is called a conditional density function.

Comment: @Christine: Please use mathjax. I edited your question so you can see immediately a few rules.

Comment: **Hint:** $f(x,y)=f_Y(y)\cdot f_{X|Y}(x,y)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of any independence assumptions, $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=f_{X|Y}(x|y) f_Y(y)$. This is just the definition of the conditional density. It looks just like the definition of conditional probability. Now the marginal density of $X$ is $f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{(X,Y)}(x,y) dy$.

Comment: Okay. How should I approach the 'problem' then? :)

Comment: @Christine Multiply to find $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, then  integrate: $f_X(x) = \int_0^\infty f_{X, Y}(x, y) \operatorname d y$